# can't append figcaption to figure (both created by createElement) Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically create a figure element, and append a figcaption to it.

```
var newFigure = document.createElement("figure");
var newPictureCaption = document.createElement("figcaption");
$(newPictureCaption).html(imgcaption); //this line is just so the caption isnt blank

$(newFigure).append(newPictureCaption);
```

however, I get the error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':
Nodes of type 'figcaption' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document-fragment'
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your code. Can you post a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a jQuery issue, your code works as expected when converted to vanilla JavaScript. I tried a typeof test, but that did not reveal much.

```js
var newFigure = document.createElement("figure");
var newPictureCaption = document.createElement("figcaption");

var targetElement = document.getElementById("test");
newFigure.appendChild(newPictureCaption);
targetElement.appendChild(newFigure);
```

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for answering, i'll be polishing up my code to find the error